# NTStatus STATUS_SUCCESS OR STATUS_WAIT_0?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winapi, error-handling

I'm P/invoking [NTQueryInformationProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a process parent's id, and i'd like to get a "readable" error in return, so i got the [NtStatus](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/NtStatus.html)  enum to cast from the return value... but i can't understand why this:

0x00000000
STATUS_SUCCESS

is (equal?) to
0x00000000
STATUS_WAIT_0 ?

first i thought it was a problem in this particular enum, but this matches the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx)

How can i differenciate it? Are both the same ? (probably a stupid question, but i see no difference..) How can i tell from success to Wait_0 in .net, so i can tell my call succeeded?

Should i just disregard STATUS_WAIT_0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't distinguish between them. The wait functions return `STATUS_WAIT_0`, `STATUS_WAIT_1`, and so on up to `STATUS_WAIT_63`. And these status codes have values, 0, 1, and so on up to 63.

So, if the code is in the range `STATUS_WAIT_0` to `STATUS_WAIT_63` inclusive, you can identify the index of the wait object that became signaled by using the expression `StatusCode - STATUS_WAIT_0`.

The wait functions that return these status codes are not documented to return `STATUS_SUCCESS`. When they succeed they are documented to return one of the `STATUS_WAIT_N` codes. So you simply never test for `STATUS_SUCCESS` when checking the return value of a wait function that is documented to return one of the `STATUS_WAIT_N` codes. Of course, finding documentation for the native API functions is quite a different matter, but that's another story.

In you case, the function you call is not a wait function. If it succeeds it returns `STATUS_SUCCESS`.

Comment: So the N is the number of milliseconds that the function waits before returning? What does it mean? The description is equal for all of them..

Comment: No, that's not what it means. Look at the documentation for `WaitForMultipleObjects`  for instance. That function waits on multiple objects, and the return value indicates which of those multiple objects satisfied the wait. None of this is remotely relevant to `NTQueryInformationProcess`. Just check the return value against `0` and be done.

Comment: So, every STATUS_WAIT_N is equal to the function succeeding?
If yes i understand it now, thanks.

Comment: It's not that simple. However, we did this dance at your previous question. I'm wise to what happens next.

Comment: Okay, i believe i understood enough from your answer, thanks again.